# React ${} string replacer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm learning React using a textbook and the string replacer ${} from this particular example doesn't work and can't figure out why. I've double checked any typos to make sure. Other examples from the book has worked fine so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      class Hello extends React.Component {
        constructor (props) {
          super(props)
          this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this) //isolates 'this' of Hello class from other 'this'
        }
        clickHandler (e) {
          const name = this.props.name
          window.alert('Hello, ${name}') //!!this doesn't work....
        }
        render () {
          return (
            <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>Say Hello</div>
          )
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render((<Hello name="Johnny" />),document.getElementById("root"))
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: replace ' by ` (tick).

Comment: don't use this '' use tick ie key above tab and below esc. So use `Hello, ${name}`

Comment: you should use back-tick

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply everyone. and great excuse to mods and admins. I always double check before I post but both from google or stack overflow, `${}` didn't yield any search result. so I had to post this question anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use back-tick

```
window.alert(`Hello, ${name}`)
```

Comment: Why does this work is that `${}` is not provided by React, it is ES6. Template literals where you can interpolate stuffs.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that this is called 'template literals'. The book didn't  provide me any details about it, since it's mainly a React book, not ES6 book.

Comment: @SungryeolPark happy to help you :)